# How to provide a global 'assert' for everyone in a Sapper app?

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, sapper

I'd like to provide a runtime `assert` to all code in a Sapper application I'm making.

*Edited:*

Bringing the [`assert`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert) module works for `server` builds, but not for `client` builds, showing either of these 500 error messages in the browser:

- `import { strict as sa } from 'assert';`

  > [image: Module specifier does not start with ...]

  With this, client build shows a warning: `'assert' is imported by src/assert.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency`
- `const sa = require("assert").strict;`

  > [image: Can't find variable: require]

  With this, client build passes. :/

My [`rollup.config.js`](https://github.com/akauppi/svg.rx.js/blob/svelte-maybe/rollup.config.js) and [`package.json`](https://github.com/akauppi/svg.rx.js/blob/svelte-maybe/package.json).

Disclaimer: I am new to Svelte and Sapper and have no idea what should be done, here. My goal is not only to get it to work, but also understand what went wrong (i.e. learn about the Sapper/Svelte packaging mechanisms).

---

<strike>*Original description:*</strike>

This should be simple. Define a global high up (the app can `import` or `require` the `assert` and place it available). In practise, I'm still confused.

I've thought about setting `window.assert` directly (a bit harsh?) and passing the value as a parameter to those components actually needing it (but parameter passing looks difficult).

This is a case of dependency injection in the way that I'd like there to be an `assert` and the lower code doesn't care, which flavour.

*Note: `console.assert` won't do because it only prints out the message. Chrome has an option for making it break. I may consider that.*

Answer (score 1):

## Server side

The `assert` module is built into `node`. For example, if you import it in `src/server.js` and call `assert(false, "whoops")` that works fine.

## Client side

Since there isn't a browser version of `assert` module, you'll need to install the npm package [assert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert) as a `devDependency` and then include it in your bundle.

This is done by importing it in `src/client.js`:

```js
// src/client.js
import assert from 'assert'

....
```

Now you can import it inside `.svelte` files too:

```html
<!-- Example.svelte -->
<script>
  import assert from assert

  assert(false, "dang it")
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason, this failed to work for me, giving the 500 in runtime that I show above. But it's good to know this should work.

Comment: Maybe try it in a blank sapper project?

Comment: Sure, I could / maybe did. The main breakthrough was the `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` issue I linked to below, though. This is not the proudest of my SO issues, but I'll keep it alive. Maybe it helps someone, one day.

Answer (score 0):

I moved on from Sapper to [svelte-filerouter](https://github.com/jakobrosenberg/svelte-filerouter) and the problems are gone. Here are the details (please comment if it works for you).

In `.svelte` or `.js` files:

```
import { assert } from 'assert';
```

In `rollup.config.js`:

```
...
   plugins: [
      resolve( {
         preferBuiltins: true,
         mainFields: ['browser'],
         dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/')
      })
   ]
```

I framed this based on [this issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/issues/107) of `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`.

---

I don't know why the 500's I got in Sapper are now gone. A lot is different if one works with Sapper as the foundation vs. just Svelte.